# Locking color scale of contour plots

Tags: r, contour, r-plotly

I’m attempting to make a series of models for soil moisture profiles and I have a series of treatments and am trying to display the change in soil moisture over time. I am attempting to do this using contour plots. I have been able to make individual plots for each each treatment at each time, but they each have a separate color scale within the same color palette (ie. a value of 10 would appear blue in some and red in others). This is obviously a problem when trying to compare plots and construct multiple subplots to visualize change over time. Is there a way to lock the color scale so I have a consistent representation of those values between treatments and subplots?

Here is my code thus far for an individual plot and my attempt at combining them into a subplot

```
on1<-plot_ly(data=idw.output,
x=~Width,
y=~Depth,
z=~Moisture, 
type=“contour”,colors=“Spectral”, reversescale=TRUE)
```

To make a single plot

```
H4<- subplot(on1, on2, on3, on4, on5, on6, on7, on8, on9,
nrows = 3, 
margin = .01, 
shareX = TRUE,
shareY = TRUE)
```

subplot displaying those plots together for each treatment

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

-Logan